# JDatePicker Popup position

Tags: java, swing, datepicker

I'm using a `org.jdatepicker.impl.JDatePanelImpl` in order to let the user choose a date prom a popup calendar.

The problem is that when the component is positioned in the bottom part of the window the popup calendar is shown below the component, and the user cannot pick a date.

Is there a way to make the popup to be shown above the `JDatePicker` component?

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.jdatepicker.impl.JDatePanelImpl;
import org.jdatepicker.impl.JDatePickerImpl;
import org.jdatepicker.impl.UtilDateModel;

public class MyDatePicker{

    JDatePanelImpl jDatePickerPanel;
    JDatePickerImpl datePicker;

    public MyDatePicker(){

        UtilDateModel model = new UtilDateModel();
        //model.setDate(20,04,2014);
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.put("text.today", "Today");
        p.put("text.month", "Month");
        p.put("text.year", "Year");
        jDatePickerPanel=new JDatePanelImpl(model, p);

        //datePicker.
        //jDatePickerPanel.getComponentPopupMenu().setLocation(100, 100);
        datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(jDatePickerPanel, new DateLabelFormatter());

    }

    public JDatePickerImpl datePicker(){

        return datePicker;
    }

    public JDatePanelImpl datePickerPanel(){

        return jDatePickerPanel;
    }

    public void setColumns(int columns){

        datePicker.getJFormattedTextField().setColumns(columns);
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Not sure it's useful, but here is the code

Comment: Any luck with this one? I'm considering moving toolbar to the top, but this is almost like accepting the failure.

Comment: I also have this problem. Any solution?